# Как установить английскую версию компилятора и линковщика на Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Примеры вывода сейчас:

> error LNK2019: ёё√ыър эр эхЁрчЁх°хээ√щ тэх°эшщ ёшьтюы
>   error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "}"

Я хочу чтобы вывод был на английском языке
   - Не изменяя язык системы

Answer (score 0):

Запускаем Visual Studio Installer (меню Средства -> Получить средства и компоненты).

В инсталляторе - Изменить -> Языковые пакеты -> выбрать нужный.

Установить

В Visual Studio Параметры -> Выбор языка -> выбрать нужный.

Вас это интересовало?